# React Form Submit

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am pretty new to react and still learning to use it.
I have a component with a form that I want to take the data during submission and transfer it to another component where I will display a card with that data. I tried several ways with props but failed
I would be grateful if someone could help me.
Thank you.

I have a component with a form that I want to take the data during submission and transfer it to another component where I will display a card with that data. I tried several ways with props but failed

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/9078341)

Comment: "I tried several ways with props" – mind including some code you've written that isn't working? Try to reduce it down to just the minimal amount needed to represent the problem in your post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like RxJs (in React, NextJS, everywhere) for reactive component communication. Check it out!

BTW: for others who think that it looks shocking, it's actually okish to write the password into state here ^^ at least according to:

[Storing form inputs in component state in React.js, specifically passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558603/storing-form-inputs-in-component-state-in-react-js-specifically-passwords)

Please just pay attention all the way, it's a password, usually you want to keep it server only and let a session decide whether to ask for it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little bit of trouble understanding *exactly* what you're looking for, but I hope this helps

### If you are trying to pass the data to just be displayed and re-rendered , but only on submit, you can do something like this:

---

Form.jsx:

```js
import InputDisplay from './InputDisplay'

export default function Form(){
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let inputUsername = event.target.elements.username.value
    let inputPassword = event.target.elements.password.value
    setUsername(inputUsername)
    setPassword(inputPassword)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={username}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
      />
      <InputDisplay
        username={username}
        password={password}
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

and then in InputDisplay.jsx:

```js
export default function InputDisplay({ username, password }){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Username: {username}</h1>
      <h1>Password: {password}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

The username and password should be re-rendered and updated only on submit in this case!

Comment: If you're updating state `onChange`, wouldn't updating state on submit always be a no-op? I.e. the state will always be the same after submit.

Comment: @Leland Good catch, I did not mean to leave the `onChange` event listeners in there... apologies